# Is it okay to show my PayPal statement along with bank statements when I apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

Is it ok to show my PayPal statement along with my bank statements when I apply for a Schengen visa? I am a freelancer and I get a lot of income from PayPal. I am wondering if it would be of help if I also print my PayPal statement when applying to the embassy?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I sure hope you don't keep large amounts of money in PayPal.   People seem to forget that PayPal is NOT a bank....they are NOT FDIC insured and they can pretty much do what they want with your money.  I keep PP tied to a bank account that never has much money in it.  Just in case PP makes a "mistake" and decides to withdraw a bunch of money.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you realize that printing paypal statements *yourself* is not evidence of anything. You could have printed into a file, edited that, and sent it to a printer afterwards. However, they might *explain* your financial situation.

Comment: Isn't that the case with pretty much all documents in this day and age?  Why would it be different for PayPal statements than, say, bank statements?

Comment: @NateEldredge, traditional bank statements are printed by the bank. The paper is from the bank. So is the ink. They're different from the printouts from an ordinary laser printer.

Comment: So are you saying that someone who wants to apply for a visa has to have traditional printed statements from their bank?  Those who use online banking are not eligible?

Comment: @NateEldredge, I'm not saying "not eligible." I'm saying that screenshots have only limited value.

Comment: @NateEldredge If applying for an UK visa printing on paper the bank statements is as good as getting your application rejected. When I used to apply for a Schengen visa, home printed statements are not accepted. You require a printout on bank stationery or from a bank  machine.

Comment: You can also print them yourself, go into the bank, and have them stamped by the bank, but at that point you might as well just go have the bank print you new copies if you don't have the original paper statements.

Comment: @DumbCoder In the U.K. at least, statements downloaded from the Bank’s online statement service bear the account holder’s full details, the Bank’s logo, branch and head office registered address, and the ‘authorised and ‘regulated by’ information. They cannot be edited and are distinct from transaction lists which are essentially no more than a printout of entries on the account. I have been assured by a Bank employee that online statements are acceptable in a court of law, and I have printed and used them without stamping by my Bank when sponsoring a successful U.K. visit visa application.

Comment: It really doesn't matter in the end because the consulates will verify the bank statements with the banks if they have any reason for suspicion.

Comment: @Traveller - `sponsoring a successful U.K. visit visa application`  That is it , not a visa for yourself. While sponsoring the other person, the other person's credibility is more of a concern if they will return back etc. If you read the guidelines for long term visas, you will see the bank stationery mentioned.

Comment: @Dumbcoder Fair enough. UK Banks encourage their customers to ‘go paperless’, hence the ability to download and print original pdf statements from their online services. Just for awareness, obtaining an ‘old fashioned’ statement these days requires the customer to opt out of paperless and you usually can’t get a statement until the changeover has taken effect. You then have to opt back in to get access to your online statements again.

Answer (score 0):

I would say ‘yes’ if your PayPal statements complete the picture of the flow of income from your freelance work into your bank account (ie demonstrate the provenance of funds) and help to reconcile your overall financial circumstances with eg your tax return.